# php - Undefined offset: 0 error when using inval() converted indexes

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to access values of my array, but getting very strange behavior.

This doesn't work and throws exception `Undefined offset: 0`:

```
$k = $sp["id"]; 
$k = intval($k); //$k prints out as int(117) here
$ship->name = $vessels[$k];
```

This works:

```
$k = 117;
$ship->name = $vessels[$k];
```

`var_dump($sp["id"])` gives me `string(3) "117"`

Can anyone explain me how is it possible?

Comment: What is the value of `$sp['id']`?

Comment: Which line gives the notice?

Comment: which line is the error?

Comment: the last one, $ship->name = $vessels[$k];

Comment: Please insert `var_dump($sp['id'])` before the last line, and post the result.

Comment: Please, just do `var_dump($vessels)` to find your reason

Comment: array(1) { [117]=> string(9) "Vessel 1" }

Comment: This is really strange, I've never encountered such a scenario before. Both codes are in the same file at the same position, aren't they?

Comment: yes, they are. Don't understand how is it possible...

Comment: Tried the code and I can't reproduce the error using the inputs you mention

Comment: can you give us some more code? maybe there is something else going on here. If this is it, it is surely strange behaviour

Comment: Can you print $vessels array here?

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
(int)$sp["id"]
```

It's also faster :)